# LEDs are burning. Cannot figure out why

Tags: led, resistors

I have a lamp that has LED driver producing 35 V (actually lamp driver says 16 - 28 V, but I've measured 35 V). On the lamp I have 7 LEDs (originally 5 + 2 I've added) with heatsinks that have burned and replaced a couple of times now. All LEDs are connected in sequence.

LEDs specs:

- LED Emitter: 3W
- Output Lumens: 180-210 Lumens
- DC Forward Voltage (VF) : 3.6-3.8Vdc
- DC Forward Current (IF) : 700mA
- Color Temp: 6000~6500K (white)
- Beam Angle: 120 degrees
- LifeSpan Time : > 50,000 hours

So I've figured out:

$$R=\frac{V_{Driver}-V_{LED} \times 7}{I_{LED}} = \frac{35\ V-3.7\ V \times 7}{0.7\ A} = 13\   \Omega\  $$

which is nothing. At the same time my LEDs are burned down within a month.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: LED DRIVER]

[image: Actual current max reading]

Comment: How much current is the driver putting out?

Comment: What is the resistance calculation for? Do you have a resistor in series?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't see the driver's current in the formula. Does it also matter?

Comment: @venny I was calculating if I need one, because of LEDs failing.

Comment: Well, yes. If your driver is putting out too much current then your LEDs will burn out.

Comment: Is the voltage of 35V measured under load? From the specification i would say this is a constant current source, and that would not be affected by adding a resistor.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thanks, I'll measure the current from driver as well.

Comment: @venny 35V is measured without the load. The driver is AC/DC converter and converts from 110V AC. Would adding a resistor help? If yes, what formula should I use to calculate that?

Comment: A CCS wouldn't be affected by resistance, as it would adjust the voltage appropriately. You need to set the current on the source directly.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams More precisely, when it reaches its maximum power, the voltage will start to drop. Probably with horrible ripple and excessive heating.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so the driver itself says 600mA +- 5%. I've measured up to 1A.

Comment: That 13 ohm is not 'nothing': it would drop 9.1V of your 35V power supply - saving your LEDs. Note it would dissipate a healthy 7 watt so you need a beefy resistor.

Comment: @RJR I wrongfully though that it was 'nothing' based on tutorials that use 1.5V battery, simple LED and 200 or 330 ohm resistor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Your "LED Driver" is most likely bad

The driver is clearly out of spec and mostly likely internally damaged. From you photos it isn't clear how the rest of your lights and power sources are connected, but you may have made an error here (I've even seen people connect the AC power line to the DC output side of the supply).

### You have a current source, not a voltage source

If you look at the label you will notice that current is specified precisely (600mA) and voltage is specified as a range (16v-28v). You will also notice that the drawings on the label show a single current loop and specify 7 3-Watt LED's in series.

That you provided this equation indicates that you are confused about the difference between the two types of sources:

$$R=\frac{V_{Driver}-V_{LED} \times 7}{I_{LED}} = \frac{35\ V-3.7\ V \times 7}{0.7\ A} = 13\   \Omega\  $$

In your equation, you cannot know the value of $$V_{Driver}$$ as it is determined by the network (it's somewhere between 16 and 28 volts if an acceptable load is attached). Only the current value is constant in the normal operating condition.

### Some background

A **voltage source** presents a single output voltage, no matter what you connect to it. To make that a true statement it will output any current the load wants up until it is incapable of outputting any more (current-limit or failure). Most people are familiar with this behavior as it is intuitive and commonly encountered.

A **current source** will **attempt** to output a **constant current** no matter the load attached to it. It will do this by adjusting the output voltage until it either can raise it no further (limit of it's upward adjustment range) or lower it no further (it will produce insufficient voltage to operate itself and shutdown).

This works via Ohm's law (V = I R) such that increasing the voltage will increase the current flowing and decreasing the voltage will decrease the current. The system is active and senses it's output current (while adjusting its output voltage) until the output current equals the number printed on the label (in this case 600mA).

If nothing (or too little load) is attached, it will output it's maximum voltage as it keeps trying to increase voltage to get increased current... and vice versa if too much load is attached.

### Driving LED's

If your LED's are connected as parallel strings of series lights, they will need to be driven by a voltage source. This configuration is cheaper to design and build, but more difficult to install and subject to greater line losses as the LED strings get bigger (since you need to bring the full voltage of the power supply all the way to the end of the line).

If your LED's are connected in series (one to the next), then the same current that drives one light will drive the next. This configuration is used in most higher-end architectural lighting. You use a current source to ensure that no matter how many lights are on the string, the current output remains the same. The advantages are that you can easily add lights to existing strings without worry. The fact that current flows through all lights ensures that voltage losses in the line are minimal (most efficient power distribution). And, LED light output is proportional to current so a current driven approach best ensures uniformity of light output.

There are some limitations however. Current drivers are more expensive as they are produced in lower quantities and have to be matched to the exact fixtures being used. The fixtures must all be the same so that they have the same light-to-current relationship and will not be too dim (or burn up) under the constant current value applied. Series wiring of light fixtures is inconvenient in some installations.

Comment: This is a really good answer.

Comment: LED's in series can also burn out due to unequal voltage drops due to variance in manufacturing, it is easy to get one "weak" one which then means the others are sharing too much voltage and hence operating outside their rating.

Comment: @JohnU Initially the lamp had 5 LEDs, but they first first melted the plastic light spreaders (don't know how they are called) and then eventually one of the LEDs was burned breaking the chain. I've replaced all 5 LEDs with the new ones and added 2 more thinking that I would "unload" the system. That didn't help as LEDs started to burn again (within a month).

Comment: @DrFriedParts thanks for explaining everything in details. Really appreciate it! Before this I've only been playing around with battery-powered circuits, and looks like battery is a voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

According to the data printed on the driver, it's a constant-current supply and it's rated to supply about 600mA into a load that can drop anywhere between 16 and 28 volts with 600mA through it, which is a load resistance range of from about 27 to 47 ohms.

Your LEDs are spec'ed to drop a nominal 3.7 volts each with 700mA through them, which makes them equivalent to about 5.3 ohms each, but that's with 700mA through them.

With 600mA through them - which is what your driver is designed to provide - the drop will be a little less, say 3.6 volts each, so they'll look like about 6 ohms each.

Seven in series, then, will look like about 42 ohms, which is pretty close to the 47 ohm ceiling for the driver and, if you add up all the tolerances, may well climb past it and overtax (fry) the driver.

Certainly with a 35 volt output pushing 1 ampere through your LED string, the driver has lost its magic smoke and is convincing the LEDs to lose theirs as well...

A solution, if you replace the driver with an equivalent unit, is not to add a series resistor to the string, but to drive only six lamps, bringing the resistance of the string  down to around 36 ohms, which the new driver should be able to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it summaries things nicely. I think @DrFriedParts pretty much has the same opinion and so I'd accept his answer (as it came first). Also, the driver burned 5 LEDs at first so I've replaced all LEDs and added 2 more thinking that I'd "unload" the system. Again, my inexperience. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any series resistor, then the answer is clear: 7 x 3.8 = 26.6V, and your driver is producing 35V.

If you DO have a series resistor (YOU SHOULD!), then it should be dropping at least 8.4V (10.5V would be better) at 700mA total current. Your ideal series resistor would be 15 ohms, but your LEDs may possibly (if run at absolute maximum ratings) be able to deal with a series resistor of only 12 ohms. Your 13-ohm resistor is running painfully close to absolute maximum.

Are your heat sinks dissipating enough power? Is it well thermally (BUT NOT ELECTRICALLY!) connected to the LEDs with a generous smear of heat sink compound? If it's a single heat sink and it's ELECTRICALLY connected to them all, then you're bypassing all but one and getting an AWFULLY high voltage across that one.

Also... since your driver is already known to be delivering SOME voltage higher than it says it SHOULD be delivering, what's the possibility that it's delivering pulses of still-higher voltage?

Comment: Well, all we know is that 35V is no-load voltage. It is a 'LED driver', it would be strange to have constant voltage driver for such high power setup.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have resistor in the series at the moment. I thought 13 ohms is very minor and wouldn't affect anything. I guess I'll have to add 15 ohms resistor

Comment: @Alex, that resistor is extremely important and is almost certainly the reason your LEDs have been burning up. Also, note the power dissipation of the resistor. With a 15 Ohm resistor, the current will be 560mA. So the power dissipation is 0.56^2*15 = 4.7W. Make sure the resistor you pick can handle that.

Comment: @DanLaks thanks! the driver also states that current output is 600mA +- 5%, but I've measured it to be up to 1A. Could it also be a factor. I still cannot figure out how driver's current output fits into the formula.

Comment: All that matters is that the current you choose for the LEDs (which is based on the resistor) is less than the maximum current the driver is spec'ed to source. That said, I think you've got a bigger problem if your driver is behaving that far outside of its spec. My guess is something has gone wrong and I wouldn't trust it any longer to power the LEDs (or anything else).

Comment: @TDHofstetter  Please use all-capitals judiciously.  In other words, please don't use all-capitals.  We have other ways to emphasize text: bold and cursive.

Comment: Personal style, developed long before bold & cursive were ever available on the Internet... old habits die hard. I do try not to let it "sound" like shouting, and it's universal - it works in comments (where bolds & cursive aren't available).

Comment: This answer is not correct for this scenario. You are describing a voltage-source. The driver in question is a current-source... and at this point it is most likely defective.

Comment: @DrFriedParts, what leads you to believe that the driver is constant-current? Which it may have been DESIGNED to be but clearly isn't, at this point... particularly since it's clearly delivering voltage far higher than its own labeling. If it's delivering 35VDC across seven series-connected 3.5V LEDs, it's obviously not limiting either its voltage or its current, so a resistor is called for to do that job.

Comment: A resistor won't fix a damaged supply, which I think he has (and/or a wiring problem). Applying a resistor here is misguided. With a current source it could result in even greater voltage output.

Comment: I'll grant all that. Most of it, anyway. The photo (new since my answer) does specifically show a label stating that the driver's output shall be limited to 28V... but we know that it's capable of delivering a higher voltage. I don't think I was guessing too wildly when I assumed that the measured 35V was open-circuit, which would indicate that the driver tops out there... in which case even a deranged constant-current driver could still be used with a 15-ohm resistor. No, it won't fix the supply, but it will allow the user to keep going with extant resources.

Comment: I don't think continuing with extant resources is wise without a maloperative theory. You are suggesting the equivalent of blindly bypassing a fuse because it keeps blowing. I believe you know what you're doing. My concerns are really just (1) it makes incorrect assertions about the architecture (you don't use resistors with current sources in general) and (2) suggests an action that is potentially dangerous if the current driver is indeed faulty -- a resistor could cause voltage spikes to go even higher potentially resulting in arcing or electric shock if someone comes in contact.

Comment: @TDHofstetter  Actually, *cursive* and **bold** are available in comments.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - I just discovered that - they're manual. Um... actually not technically cursive, but rather italic. In cursive, adjacent letters are conjoined. In italic, they're tilted.

Answer (score 0):

When a driver rated at 600mA is pushing out over 1000mA, the answer is simple: it is toasted.